# How to prevent delete px.get() for a unique_ptr

Tags: c++, c++11

On the boost.org website, I saw an example of preventing delete px.get() for a shared_ptr (http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_51_0/libs/smart_ptr/sp_techniques.html#preventing_delete).

This is a good technique and I would like to apply this using std::unique_ptr in C++11, and after tooling around for a bit, I can't quite get their example working with std::unique_ptr.

Is it possible to prevent delete px.get() from being called on a std::unique_ptr?

Here is the code from the boost.org website showing how to prevent delete px.get from being called:

```
class X
{
private:

    ~X();

    class deleter;
    friend class deleter;

    class deleter
    {
    public:

        void operator()(X * p) { delete p; }
    };

public:

    static shared_ptr<X> create()
    {
        shared_ptr<X> px(new X, X::deleter());
        return px;
    }
};
```

Comment: Protip: don't call `delete` on the pointer obtained from `std::unique_ptr::get`!

Comment: I would refrain from preventing it so the person who does so can get what's coming to them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The idea remains the same for `unique_ptr` also, except for the fact that the type of the deleter is part of the `unique_ptr`'s type.

```
#include <functional>
#include <memory>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class X
{
private:

  ~X() {}

  class deleter
  {
  public:

    void operator()(X * p) { delete p; }
  };
  friend class deleter;

public:

  static shared_ptr<X> create_shared()
  {
    shared_ptr<X> px(new X, X::deleter());
    return px;
  }

  static unique_ptr<X, void(*)(X*)> create_unique()
  {
    return unique_ptr<X, void(*)(X*)>( new X, []( X *x ) { 
                                                  X::deleter()( x ); 
                                                } );
  }

  // If using VS2010
  static unique_ptr<X, std::function<void(X*)>> create_unique()
  {
    return unique_ptr<X, std::function<void(X*)>>( new X, X::deleter() );
  }
};

int main()
{
  auto x = X::create_shared();
  auto y = X::create_unique();
}
```

VS2010 does not implement implicit conversion of capture-less lambda to a function pointer, so the first `create_unique` will not work on it.

Answer (score 2):

While calling `delete px.get()` is a pretty stupid thing to do, it's not usually something you try to prevent because it's not something you can easily do by accident. That said, here's how to fix this with unique_ptr, however it's ugly because the type of the deleter leaks into the type of the unique_ptr (why that is the case becomes clear when you look into the implementation details of unique_ptr vs. shared_ptr) and therefore the deleter has to be public, which means that the solution is not even waterproof because anybody can use the deleter. Unless you make the deleter's constructor private and make X a friend of it, however the question you also have to ask yourself is why bother? Somebody has to intentionally do the wrong thing by writing `delete px.get()` for it to become a problem.

```
class X
{
private:
   ~X() {}

public:
    struct deleter
    {
        void operator()(X * p) { delete p; }
    };

    static std::unique_ptr<X, deleter> create()
    {
      std::unique_ptr<X, deleter> px(new X, deleter());
      return px;
    }
};
```

Comment: "*it's not usually something you try to prevent because it's not something you can easily do by accident.*" Nobody calls `delete px.get()`. What they do is get a naked pointer to an object, stick it somewhere for a while, then forget that they don't own it so they try to delete it. This at least attempts to make it a compile error. Also, the deleter should be private.

Comment: @NicolBolas When you pass around plain pointers to objects that are managed by smart pointers you should do so in the form of references.

Comment: You don't need to make the deleter public (that defeats the whole purpose of this question). Even if you include the deleter in the `unique_ptr`'s type as you have done, the user can always use `auto` to create the an instance, they just won't be able to specify the type explicitly. Another way is to not include the deleter in the type, but add an abstraction like I have in my answer.

Comment: @SegFault: Unless you can't use references because you might pass NULL.

Comment: Ok, it appears that we would need more information. What exactly are the use cases for the plain pointers extracted from the managed pointer? What exactly are we trying to guard against, stupidity and/or stray delete in legacy code? ...

Comment: @Prætorian I had thought of the `auto`, but it would depend on how the pointers are used whether that's enough. I hadn't thought of hiding the type of the deleter like you did, good idea, if probably with quite some overhead.

Comment: Only the `std::function` method will have overhead, the other one should be the same as including the deleter in the type.

Comment: Ah, I had missed the change to the standard that allows you to portably use a lambda with empty capture list like a function pointer.

Comment: One of the motivations behind locking down access to the class' destructor is because of developers I work with. Unfortunately, not all of them understand shared_ptr's and why it is terrible to call delete px.get(). These same developers will also do const_cast on an object that should not be modified, but that is a discussion for a separate thread.